# A "simple" question about the order of subgroups of the group of additive integers

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Simple, but I cannot answer it.

Let $\mathbb Z_n$ be the additive group of integers with order $n$. Suppose $m$ is a factor of $n$. Then $\mathbb Z_n$ contains a subgroup of order $m$.

I am trying to solve this from first principles and no recourse to Lagrange or other theorems.

Comment: Welcome  to MSE , 1. This iste uses [MathJAx](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) for mathematic formulations

Comment: Thank you. I'm just learning to navigate myself around. What a wonderful place this is.

Comment: @JacopoStifani Since you are new, I edited the quesiton for you. Think of it as a welcome gift. I changed your Z into $\mathbb Z$ by writing `$\mathbb{Z}$` (just like in LaTeX). I also deleted your last sentence. There is no need to end questions with a "Thank you for answering".

Comment: Ok, well can I thank others in the comments section then? Or do we leave all formalities aside when answering math questions?

Answer (score 2):

It will not get any more elementary than this: We have $\mathbb Z_n = \{0,1,2, \dotsc, n-1\}$. Show that

$$\Big\{0,\frac{n}{m}, \frac{2n}{m}, \dotsc, \frac{(m-1)n}{m}\Big\}$$

is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$. It obviously has $m$ elements.

Comment: Wonderful, and thank you for the immediate response.